# Silent git commit if no changes are made

Tags: git

I want to make git stay silent if there is nothing to commit. Or at least not do a costly `git status`. (I have a lot of untracked files so enumerating them takes ages ...)

Comment: I don't get it.  If the working directory and stage in fact are empty, then `git status` should only return 1-2 sentences informing you of this.  If they are _not_ empty, then yes you might get back verbose output, but that's the reality, right?

Comment: Can you put the untracked files/directories/etc.  in .gitignore?

Comment: @Joe It’s my home directory. I use `vcsh`. I can’t gitignore that many patternless files.

Comment: You can call `git status -uno` to ignore untracked files.

Comment: @larsks Yes, I can. The problem is I am not the one calling git status. git commit does it itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ git commit -uno
On branch master
nothing to commit
```